# Density plot for point-like divergences

Tags: plotting

Shown below is the Plot3D and DensityPlot of a dataset i have generated. I want to be able to see the peaks shown in the plot3d on the density plot but they don't seem to show up and I was wondering if there was a way to fix this?
[image: 3dplot][image: density plot]

Also, if possible I was wondering if there was a way (either for the density plot or the 3d plot) to make the plotting region hexagonal. The usual method i use (creating a hexregion and assigning it to the regionfunction) seems to create something Lovecraftian...

[image: lovecraftian horror]

The relevant code is here:

```
    anew = {{1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}};
d = {{Cos[kvec . anew[[1]]] + Cos[kvec . anew[[2]]] + 
     1}, {Sin[kvec . anew[[1]]] + Sin[kvec . anew[[2]]]}, {delta + 
     2*t2*
      Sin[
       phi]*(Sin[kvec . anew[[1]]] - Sin[kvec . anew[[2]]] - 
        Sin[kvec . (anew[[1]] - anew[[2]])])}};
Inner[Times, PauliMatrix[Range[3]], d, Plus, 1];
ham2[kx_, ky_, delta_, t2_, phi_] = %[[All, All, 1]];
ham2[KX, KY, DELTA, T2, PHI] // MatrixForm

kxrange = N[Range[-2*Pi + Pi/100, 2*Pi - Pi/100, 4*Pi/100]];
kyrange = N[Range[-2*Pi + Pi/100, 2*Pi - Pi/100, 4*Pi/100]];
t2val = 0.0;
phival = Pi/2;
deltaval = 0.1;
ham2[KX, KY, deltaval, t2val, phival];
ham = %;
Eigensystem[ham2[KX, KY, deltaval, t2val, phival]];
{anaeigvals, anaeigvecs} = %;
I*(Conjugate[D[anaeigvecs, KX]] . D[anaeigvecs, KY] - 
    Conjugate[D[anaeigvecs, KY]] . D[anaeigvecs, KX]);
berry[KX_, KY_] = %;
hexRegion = Region[RegularPolygon[2 \[Pi], 6]];
Plot3D[Re[berry[KX, KY]], {KX, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {KY, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, {x, y} \[Element] hexRegion]]
```

Comment: Have a look at "ham2" it does not depend on kx and ky.

Comment: When I run your  code on version 12.3 I get:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR0aO.png

Comment: Ah apologies! You just need to define kvec={kx,ky}. That was an error on my part. For reference, the code cited is the attempt to ply over the hecagonal region - if you just remove the RegionFunction part of the code you will obtain the graphs above.

Comment: The lovecraftian plot has PlotRange {-.5 10^-16, .5 10^16}.  What you are seeing is numerical artifacts.  Usually Mathematica can get the right range automatically, in this case it doesn't.  Set `PlotRange->{-1,1}` to obtain a more sensible plot (though it seems to be multivalued) https://imgur.com/a/tTjjbhe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the very last line where you are plotting, use [Chop](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html).

```
Plot3D[Chop[Re[berry[KX, KY]]], {KX, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {KY, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, {x, y} \[Element] hexRegion]]
```

This is because, as you can see in your plot the numerical outputs are of the order of $10^{-16}$, which is zero with respect to peak values.

[image]

Or you can also use PlotRange -> Full.

```
Plot3D[Re[berry[KX, KY]], {KX, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {KY, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, {x, y} \[Element] hexRegion], 
PlotRange -> Full]
```

It will give you the same result.

Comment: Ah thank you that's really helpful!

Comment: I was wondering if its possible to make the colorfunction show a change in colors for the peaks? for some reason it doesn't seem to show up at all.